# Two fonts with the same name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont

I have to use two fonts in my app:

`font1.ttf` and is name : `CustomFont`

`font2.ttf` and is name : `CustomFont`

The two fonts are with the same name, but the only different is the file name and that font1 is normal and font2 is bold.
As i read i need to add to `UIAppFonts` array of the fonts name and not the file name.
What can i do in my case that the two font have the same font name?

This is how i use `font1.ttf`:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont" size:24.0];
```

Comment: If both the fonts have the same name (bad idea) I believe your app is going to use the first one it finds. Why not get rid of one of the duplicates? I am sure you can find a similar one by googling free fonts and that will have a different name

Comment: EXEC is right. You're just asking for problems here. Switch fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who created the fonts? What make you think that the fonts got the same name? I doubt that someone created a font with the name x and then did a weight on that font with the name x and not x Bold.
Right click on the TTF -> Get Info and check the field  "Full Name". There's a good chance that you'll see a different name for each file. If that's not the case I would strongly advise to change one of the fonts name to avoid future confusion.